# Какие технологии, стеки использовать для размещения отпарсенной инфы на web-странице?

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, jinja

Написал парсер по собиранию картинок. Вместе с картинками идет и некоторая информация к ним. Программа запускалась со строки картинки собирались в файл инфа в csv или json (и так и так реализовано). Но все это не красиво как-то. Не удобно.

Сейчас существует множество технологий, всевозможных стеков и т.д. Какие из них мне нужны, чтобы эту всю полученную инфу разместить на web-странице? Т.е., чтобы каждая картинка с инфой отдельным блоком одна за другой.

1. Python - для парсинга
2. Flask - нужен или нет? Если да, то для чего?
3. Jinja - нужна или нет?
4. Vue - нужен или нет?
5. ...может что-то другое надо?
   Помогите разобраться.

Как я понимаю, если сначала необходимо было скачивание картинок и инфы, то для размещения их на web-странице нужны только их url?

Answer (score 1):

Итак, вы парсите через Python, а значит логично писать веб интерфейс на фреймворках для Python. Flask - это Фреймворк для написания backendа веб серверов, т.е. обработку http запросов, обработка инфы из этих запросов и много чего ещё. Без этого фреймворка у вас вряд - ли что - то получится.  Jinja - шаблонизатор HTML шаблонов. Весь фронт на вебе в основе лежит на html. Шаблонизатор позволяет в удобной форме вставлять контент на страницу(например разные значения переменных). Vue - фреймворк для js. Ну в вашем случае он не нужен, как и например react. Flask + Jinja вам достаточно. Но стоит обратить внимание на bootstrap. Это фреймворк, который вы сможете использовать внутри html. Он позволит не заморачиваться над версткой. Там есть готовые стили для тех же таблиц, которые вам нужны. С картинками всё верно, нужны только их url.